# Changing ipython version on Anaconda for Emacs EIN

Tags: python-3.x, emacs, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to use Emacs as Python IDE. I want it to work with Anaconda so as to run EIN and interact with Jupyter notebook.. (pandas, numpy, scipy, matplotlib..)

I originally followed [this article](https://realpython.com/blog/python/emacs-the-best-python-editor/) for setting emacs up. I've installed elpy, flycheck, and ein. Then, I run emacs 25.3.1 Python 3.6.3 ipython 6.1.0
Linux Manjaro.
There is an issue with IPython starting at version 4, that basically the new Ipython isn't compatible with the emacs shell. It DOES work in term mode , but not with EIN:

- https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24453/weird-shell-output-when-using-ipython-5
- https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9816

---

**First problem** I'm having: a messy screen in IPython.

The solution would be downgrading Anaconda, which is where I fail.

Then, it comes the **second problem**... I tried `conda list --revisions` but it only gives me the last three revisions so I can't revert to ipython4 which is the safe zone, it appears.

I tried conda to install a specific ipython4 zip but it refused to launch, perhaps it has dependencies that need replacing. I would like to use Anaconda and not pip install it as I find the Anaconda text completion and all features superior.

Here is the EIN project documentation:
https://github.com/millejoh/emacs-ipython-notebook

Any suggestions on that?

Comment: meanwhile, I found the continuum archive page and downloaded anaconda3 4.1.1, which is the last before ipython4. Everything seem to work for now in the ein front.

Comment: I use Ipython 6.1 with python 2/3 and there are no problems running in emacs. Are you passing `--simple-prompt` as suggested in both the linked answers? Personally, i used the following for `python-shell-interpreter-args` running on linux, `"-i --matplotlib=auto --pylab=auto --colors=Linux --simple-prompt"`

Comment: @jenesaisquoi I didn't want to use the --simple-prompt so as not to loose the Ipython functionality that I find superior to the autocomplete and docstring scripts that are recommended in those quoted articles. But my expirience is not that big, do you find that your setup is sufficient and complete? As I already rolled back to IPython 4 I can't try it right now, unless two versions of IPython can be installed and run in parallel.

Comment: Yea it works great for me, although I use anaconda-mode, not elpy. If you’re using conda already you could just use two environments